# How to delete entry from MemoryIdempotent in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, idempotent

How can delete an entry (a filename that has been processed) from MemoryIdempotent in apache camel

Comment: The goal of such idempotent repository is to keep track of all already processed files (so that they are not consumed twice). If each time a file is processed, you systematically delete the corresponding entry in the repo, it means that you obviously do not need itempotency ? In general, you do not have to take take care about deleting entries; this will be done automatically by Camel (for instance when the size limit is reached).

Comment: If **really** needed, there is `remove(key)` method on the class `MemoryIdempotentRepository` - See https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-support/3.0.0/org/apache/camel/support/processor/idempotent/MemoryIdempotentRepository.html